# How do i get a internet connection to proxmox vm

Tags: networking, proxmox

I have installed proxmox VE 7.1-7 to a hetzner dedicated server and i am having problems with getting internet connection to virtual machines

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp41s0
iface enp41s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    address <Main IP>/26
    gateway <gateway>
    bridge-ports enp41s0
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
```

Comment: probably some information there: https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/ip/additional-ip-adresses/ . You have to declare additional MAC addresses, or else route rather than bridge. also netmask 255.255.255.255 disagrees with /26, whatever you meant to do.

Comment: How many public addresses do you have ?